# Unable to interact with lockscreen after installing bumble bee

Tags: display, greeter, input, bumblebee

I recently installed bumblebee to set my Nvidia gpu as default for steam.

After reboot the lock screen or any display never came up, so I booted into recovery and purged bumblebee,

Upon next reboot, I got it to display the lock screen, but now I cannot interact with it in any way.

I can still use the recovery mode to interact with the root terminal with no issues, and my windows dual boot is working fine as well, so I don't think it has anything to do with the hardware.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just removing all Nvidia drivers through root terminal in recovery fixed the problem

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia*
```